# Why won't the Master Cycle and Ancient Horse Armor work in Normal Mode?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild, with the DLC purchased, I have both the Master Cycle and Ancient Horse Armor in Normal Mode but they won't work. The Master Cycle keeps saying it can't spawn, and the horse gear doesn't even work.
Does it only work in Master Mode? Because when I'm in Master Mode they do work.

Comment: just wondering... have you by any chance glitched out of the Ganon fight on your normal save?

Comment: no, i have not . in the past i have tried but i haven't successfully

Comment: On that same save file? Perhaps you may have triggered the permanent "game thinks you are in a small room" bug even if you weren't successful... I don't know the details. Yet **IF** that was the case, though luck - your file would be forever stained. Notice that I am not suggesting this is the case, it is just that every reference I can find to this problem ends up mentioning that glitch being the cause.

Comment: hmm thank you but when i do ¨try¨ i give up because i don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

if you are at:

- (inside) hyrule castle
- Gerudo Desert
- forgotten temple
- shrine
- Death Mountain/anywhere in eldin that is near lava,it wont work.

I would check what part of the ancient hprse armor you have equipped. is it the saddle? if so it should work maybe you should restart your system. If its the bridle then you have the wrong part equipped. If you have both equipped, restart your system.
and for the master cycle check the fuel. It may be empty. if so, you should use Monster Extract, as it is the best fuel source, as 5 of them make a full tank.